# basic sql server subquery, how it impact performance?

Tags: sql-server

Do this SQL query has a performance penalty?

> select fullname, address from (select  (name + ' ' + lastname) as fullname, address from mytable) as tab

Compare with:

> select  (name + ' ' + lastname) as fullname, address from mytable

Maybe you think.. Why I want to do this, the reason is because SQL Server not allow to use alias in group by, so usign subquery I can do this

> select fullname, address from (select  (name + ' ' + lastname) as fullname, address from mytable) as tab group by fullname

Instead of

> select  (name + ' ' + lastname) as fullname, address from mytable group by name + ' ' + lastname

This is just an example, where alias is and alias of a basic concatenation, but something concatenation are more complex and rewrite it into group clause is really ugly.

Answer (score 3):

The subquery in itself is not likely to cause performance problems. The query planner will probably rearrange the query so that it's not a subquery at all in the end. Looking at the performance plan would reveal what actually happening to the query.

What might be a performance problem is that you are grouping on a calculated value. That means that the database can't use any index for the grouping, so it has to create all values and then sort them.

If possible you should group on the values that are used in the calculation, for example:

```
select name + ' ' + lastname as fullname
from mytable
group by name, lastname
```

Comment: nice, this cover a lot of situation, maybe not where column use some dynamic content (like function return value), but for static and column values this is OK :)

Comment: My preference is to avoid nested selects because 1) I do believe they cause performance issues when queries get complex and 2) I find them harder to follow/read. Also, if you have dynamic content, I'd either list the function twice (once in the group by, once in the select list), create a view (persisted if possible) with the needed functions or add Persisted, calculated columns as DSharper suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully but in general, subqueries will have a negative effect on performance and should be avoided. Why don't you use the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) syntax?

```
select CONCAT(name, ' ', lastname) as fullname, address from mytable group by CONCAT(name, ' ', lastname);
```

Depending on your situation and complexity, you may also want to look at [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: because is really ugly to put all CONCAT in group by, if I change something in the CONCAT column I must replicate this change to group by.

Answer (score 0):

One option to improve performance might be to create a computed column with Persisted keyword named as fullname.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[yourtable] ADD
fullname AS (firstname+' '+lastname) PERSISTED
GO
--instead of SELECT firstname + ' ' + lastname, address FROM dbo.[yourtable]     
SELECT fullname, address 
FROM dbo.[yourtable]
```